# Where would this question go: "Why is the drop shadow light source always upper left?"

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if this really fits with graphic design, ux, or something else.

Comment: Are you referring to the light source in a GUI such as MS Windows? If yes, I think this is a very good question. I am wondering too. However I do think that most GUIs are stepping away from that principle. Drop shadow is something that seems to be replaced by outer glow these days.

Comment: Yes, referring to GUI. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 3):

Your question contains an assumption that you haven't explained, so I don't think it's a good question. You'll need to explain that before I can give you a recommendation either way. The answer could relate to something like "Photoshop's default lighting angle happens to be that, and lazy people don't change it, so there you go" or it could get very psychological if someone starts talking about the fact that people tend to look at art (and UI) from the top left towards the bottom right.

So depending on what your context is, you may get a different answer, and you may want to post it on a different site.